# uninstall eclipse features by command line

Tags: eclipse, equinox, p2

Installing eclipse features by command line is well known[1].

However, I have a problem to uninstall eclipse features by command line.

I use the following command.

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse \
-repository \
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon,\
https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.6,\
http://pydev.org/updates"
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-uninstallIU \
org.eclipse.egit.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.help.feature.group
```

The output is the following.

```
Uninstalling org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 4.4.1.201607150455-r.
Uninstalling org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group 3.21.0.v20160914-0252.
Uninstalling org.eclipse.help.feature.group 2.2.1.v20161124-1400.
```

However, when I start the eclipse, the plugins still there.
Any help?

[1] http://blog.vogella.com/2012/04/04/installing-eclipse-features-via-the-command-line-with-the-p2-director/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run the p2 garbage collector after uninstallation of the features.
You can run the GC manually from the command line with a command like:
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application
-profile SDKProfile
[Plug-in jar remains after feature uninstall](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=543500)

Comment: Peter, thank you for the answer. I already did that too, but I did not succeed.